# PyQt5 - QStandardItem.setText() не показывает текст

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, tableview, qstandarditemmodel

Существует некоторая `QStandardItemModel`, которая создана для использования некоторым `QTableView`. Нижеследующий код пытается создать `QStandardItemModel`, наполнить её и подключить к `QTableView`.

Проблема заключается в том, что все тексты `QStandardItem` внутри `QStandardItemModel` не отображаются в `QTableView`.

[image: Скриншот того, что получается после выполнения нижеследующего кода]

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui

myModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(1, 4)
myModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Тип', 'Порт', 'Описание', 'МП | МГ'])

lu = []
item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
item.setText('Arduino')
lu.append(item)

item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
item2.setText('COM5')
lu.append(item2)

item3 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
item3.setText('description')
lu.append(item3)

item4 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
item4.setText('<html><head/><body><p> 1 | <span style=" color:#8cdc52;"1 </span></p></body></html>')
lu.append(item4)

myModel.appendRow(lu)
myListView.setModel(myModel)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пожалуйста предоставляйте **ВОСПРОИЗВОДИМЫЙ** пример. Я не совсем понял, почему в вопросе вы пишите о виджете `QListView`, а самом коде используете все для `QTableView`?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QListView, QTableView


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

myModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 4)
myModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Тип', 'Порт', 'Описание', 'МП | МГ'])

lu = []
item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
item.setText('Arduino')
lu.append(item)

item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
item2.setText('COM5')
lu.append(item2)

item3 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
#item3.setText(unit['description'])
item3.setText(', '.join(['description1', 'description1']))
lu.append(item3)

item4 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
item4.setText('<html><head/><body><p> 1 | <span style=" color:#8cdc52;"1 </span></p></body></html>')
lu.append(item4)

myModel.appendRow(lu)

view  = QTableView()               # QListView()
view.setModel(myModel)
view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: прошу прощения, опечатался. Спасибо.